# Proxmox how to remove disk from node

Tags: proxmox

Am new to proxmox wondering how can we remove disks from proxmox as you can see i have somes disks mounted

[image]

**What i did to remove them**

```
systemctl disable mnt-pve-ISOs.mount

umount /mnt/pve/ISOs
```

i checked nano `/proc/mounts`   ISOs disk entry is not there

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/mnt-pve-ISOx.mount
```

have removed ISOs entry from `nano /etc/pve/storage.cfg`

and rebooted server , but still these disks are mounted and where i try to create directory none of the drive show up except one drive which i have not added to proxmox.

[image]